# Set cancel_at for subscription using checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been testing stripe checkout for a few days in order to set-up subscription payments for a company. Stripe checkout is very easy to use but it seems to add some constraints. In particular, I want to set the subscription cancel_at property (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at) and it does not seem to be possible using checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create). Maybe I have missed something ? Or should I create the subscription using the checkout and update it later ?
Has anyone found a solution ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Checkout doesn't support an equivalent to the subscription's [cancel_at](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at) parameter. The workaround would be to use Checkout to create the subscription, and later use a subscription-update call server-side to set a [cancel_at](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at) date:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update

You can do this immediately after the subscription is created by listening to the [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event, which will contain the newly-created [subscription ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-subscription). You can read more on how to listen for events from Stripe in these guides here:

- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#webhooks
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/integration-builder

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! That's what I was thinking of doing (I have already the webhook set-up).
But to my mind, it's a bit a pity because in term of message, the customer can be lost. It would be nice to add the cancel_at in the checkout process so that the customer can see before paying that he has a limited subscription period.
Thanks again !,
Best